# get value of a field from json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "A1",
    "aaaaa": [
        {
            "name": "B1",
            "teststr": [
                {
                    "name": "C1",
                    "state": false,
                },
                {
                    "name": "C2",
                    "state": false,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "B2",
            "teststr": [
                {
                    "name": "C3",
                    "state": false,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using JavaScript.

Now, within A1, I have to find a specific "testStr" with name "C1" and change its "state" from false to true. Keys "aaaaa" and "teststr" are unique. And all "teststr"s have unique name.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your question received an answer about twenty-five minutes ago, do you still need it?

Comment: @myTerminal and what does that exactly mean? I am new to posting questions on stackoverflow, Am I missing some specific workflow or what?

Comment: Thanks @Medha Dev, just was curious if my answer helped. Wasn't quite sure myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go this way:

```
var smallObject = object.aaaaa.filter(function (o) {
    return o.name === "B1";
})[0];

var smallerObject = smallObject.teststr.filter(function (o) {
    return o.name === "C1";
})[0];

smallerObject.state = true;
```

Where `object` is the literal object that you mentioned in the problem definition.